# Echo3 Framework - problem setting focus elemnt to text box when screen is built

Tags: java, frameworks, echo3

in echo 3 i have a problem setting focus on a specific text field in a new screen. The probelm occurs when a user holds their mouse on the reference button on the previous screen as opposed to just a simple click.

it looks similar to this:

```
public void display screen {
    build window
    if window isnt null{
        build screen
        if screen.textfield isnt null{
            Thread t {
                thread sleep 10000
                screen.textfield.setFocus
            }

        }

    }

}
```

in the pseudo above the focus would be set if the user user held the reference button down on the screen before for less than 10 seconds, in which case the focus would not be set until the remaining thread time passed. this isnt good because it take too long; and lower wait delay doesnt insure that the focus will set at all because the user might hold the key for longer.

I have tried launching multiple threads and using timers to hammer the focus in but that didnt work... is there something im missing about how the code is built internally because it seems that the whole thing is built despite the fact that the user hasnt let go of the button.

If thats the case is there a way to do it on release?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. The problem was with using IE6. I presume the order in which it builds is different to that of IE7+.